# How to select all possible combination of elements from a set using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

This is a question from hackerrank; I am trying to understand how recursion works.

The task at hand is:

> Find the number of ways that a given integer, **X**, can be expressed
>   as the sum of the **N**th power of unique, natural numbers.
>
> So for example, if **X = 100** and **N = 2**
>
> 100 = 10² = 6² + 8² = 1² + 3² + 4² + 5² + 7²
>
> so 100 can be expressed as the square of unique natural numbers in 3
>   different ways, so our output is 3.

Here is my code,:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int numOfSums(int x, int& n, const int k) {

    int count = 0, j;
    for (int i = (k + 1); (j = (int) pow(i, n)) <= x; i++) {
        j = x - j;

        if (j == 0)
            count++;
        else
            count += numOfSums(j, n, i);
    }

    return count;
}

int main() {
    int x, n;
    cin >> x >> n;
    cout << numOfSums(x, n, 0) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I input x = 100 and n = 2, it's outputting `2`, not `3`. What's wrong with the code?

**Link to the question:** https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-power-sum

Comment: Start by adding comments to your code and naming variables with descriptive names such that people can look at your code and figure out your intention in 2 seconds rather than 2 minutes. Even when dealing with math problems as described. int exponent; is far better than int n;...No Wait....start by drawing your algorithm on paper with a pencil, then do that....What is k supposed to be and why did you name it k? Also hackerrank has forums for their questions, you can view other's solutions there.

Comment: Beware that that `(int)pow(i, n)` could round down.  `(int)(pow(i, n) + 0.5)` is safer, but it's probably better to implement an integer function instead of round-tripping through `double`.

Comment: Hey, I've tried your could and it gave me 3.

Comment: yea creating a seperate power function did the trick, I don't really understand why though....

Comment: @Christopher Pisz, this is an easy level question, and plenty of people have already asked for an explanation on hacker rank, but no responses. And I find it very difficult to write recursive algorithms. Draw what on paper with a pencil? How do I name my variables properly?

Comment: To be honest, I don't even know why this code works, it all seems really confusing right now.

Comment: I mean draw out each frame of the recursion and what each variable should look like in that frame. You'll have a frame for the initial call, then a frame for the call within the initial, then a frame for a call within that call, etc. then you can trace through it visually. Also, trace through it as each call returns and the call stack rewinds.

Comment: Also, can you please link the hackerrank problem page so we can make sure no details are missing? I'll try this problem out tonight when I get home and post at least one solution on their forums.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to visualise the recursive process in terms of frames. And I linked the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example code returns `3` when I run it using this `main()`:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int x = 100, n = 2;
    cout << numOfSums(x, n, 0) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is likely that you're using `double std::pow(double, int)`, but you're not rounding the result to nearest integer (`(int)` casts round down).  You should add ½ before truncating:

```
j = static_cast<int>(pow(i, n) + 0.5)
```

I've used the more-C++ style of cast, which I find clearer.

It would be more efficient to implement your own equivalent of `std::pow()` that operates on integers.  That can be recursive, too, if you want:

```
unsigned long pow(unsigned long x, unsigned long n)
{
    return n ? x * pow(x, n-1) : 1;
}
```

An iterative version is more efficient (or a tail-recursive version and suitable optimizing compiler).

Reduced version, with my changes:

```
template<typename T>
T powi(T x, T n)
{
    T r{1};
    for (;  n;  n /= 2) {
        r *= n%2 ? x : 1;
        x *= x;
    }
    return r;
}

template<typename T>
T numOfSums(T x, T n, T i = {})
{
    T count{}, j;
    for (++i;  (j = powi(i, n)) <= x;  ++i)
        count += j == x ? 1 : numOfSums(x-j, n, i);
    return count;
}

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    unsigned long int x = 100, n = 2;
    std::cout << numOfSums(x, n) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why doesn't c++ have this version of pow built-in?

Comment: @Rockstar, from C++11 onwards there's a templated version: [`Promoted    pow( Arithmetic1 base, Arithmetic2 exp );`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow), but that still converts arguments to `double`.  It's probably because C can't do overloads, and `<cmath>` is still mostly C.